# How to make a whole website run under fullscreen with screenfull.js?

Tags: javascript, iframe, fullscreen

I am using the screenfull.js library and I have a button that in which I attach the event for the click to go fullscreen. I can enter fullscreen mode but then as soon as I click on something, the fullscreen is exit.

I've been told that the fullscreen api is meant to be used on a single page. There are ways to work around this by using this iframe trick https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js/blob/gh-pages/index.html#L202-L219.

```
// a little hack to be able to switch pages while in fullscreen.
// we basically just creates a seamless iframe and navigate in that instead.
$('#iframe').click(function () {
      // We create an iframe and fill the window with it
      var iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
      iframe.setAttribute('id', 'external-iframe');
      iframe.setAttribute('src', 'http://bbc.com');
      iframe.setAttribute('frameborder', 'no');
      iframe.style.position = 'absolute';
      iframe.style.top = '0';
      iframe.style.right = '0';
      iframe.style.bottom = '0';
      iframe.style.left = '0';
      iframe.style.width = '100%';
      iframe.style.height = '100%';
      $('#container').prepend(iframe);
      document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
})
```

However, I don't get it the trick with the iframe. Sorry I am a noob in JS. I have lots of links/request inside my app and what I want to make fullscreen is my whole app. With the iframe trick I would need to make each button use the iframe? Is there a workaround?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: With the iframe trick you serve your whole site in the iframe. The full screen page has only one content: the iframe and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/screenfull.js/1.0.4/screenfull.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#go-full').click(function(){
            if (document.fullscreenEnabled) {
                requestFullscreen($('#my-full-site')[0]);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<button id="go-full">Go Fullscreen</button>
<iframe id="my-full-site" src="http://example.com"></iframe>
```

You need to create this as a new page. You can't trigger fullscreen from within your iframe and be able to navigate away.

Comment: Hi. Thanks Pastudan. I did something similar to what you recommend here. And it works!!! thanks! One small issue is that each time I do a request in the iframe (whether I am fullscreen or not), the browser does a little flash (whole white page) until the request returns and the page is rendered. Any idea what this could be?